# Can you use a data flow sink as a source in the same data flow?

Tags: azure-data-factory, pipeline, azure-synapse

I am trying to load the sales data to the database using Azure Synapse Analytics pipelines, and the strategy is as follows (scenario is made up):

1. Load the students` data to the table Students
2. Load the students` classes information to the table StudentsClasses. In this data flow I need to join the data with the Students table (obviously, the new data about students must be loaded to Students at this join step)

Can I have these two processes in the same data flow with Sink ordering? Or does the sink ordering not define source read ordering? (that is, the source reading and transformations are done in parallel, and only the write is according to the ordering?

Edit: This is an example data flow that I want to implement:
[image]

source3 and sink1 are the same table. What I want is to first populate sink1, then use it for source 2 to join with it. Can this be implemented using Sink ordering? Or source3 will be empty regardless of sink ordering?

Comment: What is your source type or dataset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use multiple source and sinks in a single data flow and reference same source over join activity. And order sink write using Custom sink ordering property

I am using Inline dataset but you can use any type

Using **inline dataset** to store the result in **sink1**. In **source3**, use the same **inline dataset** to join with **Source2**

[image]

---

[image]

Make sure you give the sink order correctly, if you have the wrong order or if it encounters no data while proceeding with transformation, it will publish with no errors however the pipeline run would fail.

[image]

Refer MS DOC: [Sink ordering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-sink#custom-sink-ordering)

Comment: I have edited my question to more clearly show what I wanted to implement

Comment: please check updated, there is no explicit way to set source ordering, however if you have transformation that dosent match the data order it would fail at runtime

Comment: If I have 1 Source SQL table and for every record in that table I need to process it and insert it into 3 target tables, how would I ensure that each record from source gets probably inserted in ALL 3 tables or not at all? Is this a matter of putting all 3 sinks to write order 1?